# Configure DNS to point site at web host when mail is through Google Apps?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, godaddy

I have my DNS records set up so that I can use Google Apps (email) with my own domain, but I want to use my web host account (Lunarpages) to host my website.  This is a little over my head.  My registrar is GoDaddy.

Thanks for any help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you've already [configured your mx records to point to Google](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33353), all you need to do is set your A record. Your web host should have provided you with an IP address that your website is hosted at. Like so:

[image: Godaddy DNS A record]